# find the length of rectangle based on area of frame

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A rectangular picture is $3$ cm longer than its width, $(x+3)$. A frame $1$ cm wide is placed around the picture. The area of the frame alone is $42 \text{cm}^2$. Find the ***length*** of the picture.[image]

I have tries:

$(x+6)(x+3) = 42 \\
x^2+3x+6x+12 = 42 \\
x^2+9x+12x-42 = 0 \\
\\
x^2 + 21 -42$

Comment: Does "length" refer to the "width" or height of the picture. Basically the $x+3$ or $x+6$?

Comment: @JulianRachman according to the question text, height as we look at it.

Comment: Obviously, $x$ represents the length of my nose, so the width is 3cm longer than my nose and the length is 6 cm longer than my nose. This problem is poorly posed, not to mention the grammatical error in the first sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Area $A$ of the $1$-cm-wide frame in cm$^2$ is $2\times $ height $+ 2\times $ width $+ 4$ (for the corners).

$A = 2 (x+3) + 2(x+6)+4 = 4x+22 = 42$

$\implies x=5$

The length is $(x+6) = 11$ cm

Answer (score 2):

The area of the frame is the difference between the area of the rectangle bordered by the outside of the frame and the area of the picture. Since the frame adds $1~\text{cm}$ on each side of the picture, the outer rectangle has length $x + 8~\text{cm}$ and width $x + 5~\text{cm}$.  Thus, the area of the frame is
\begin{align*}
(x + 8~\text{cm})(x + 5~\text{cm}) - (x + 6~\text{cm})(x + 3~\text{cm}) & = 42~\text{cm}^2\\
(x^2 + 13x~\text{cm} + 40~\text{cm}^2) - (x^2 + 9x~\text{cm} + 18~\text{cm}^2 & = 42~\text{cm}^2\\
4x~\text{cm} + 22~\text{cm}^2 & = 42~\text{cm}^2\\
4x~\text{cm} & = 20~\text{cm}^2\\
x~\text{cm} & = 5~\text{cm}
\end{align*}
Hence the length of the picture is $x + 6~\text{cm} = 5~\text{cm} + 6~\text{cm} = 11~\text{cm}$.

Comment: how to get length x+8 and width x+5?

Comment: Look at the diagram.  Note that the width of the picture is $x + 3~\text{cm}$.  On each side of the picture, the frame is $1~\text{cm}$ wide, so the width of the picture together with the frame is $$1~\text{cm} + x + 3~\text{cm} + 1~\text{cm} = x + 5~\text{cm}$$  By similar reasoning, the length of the picture with the frame is $$1~\text{cm} + x + 6~\text{cm} + 1~\text{cm} = x + 8~\text{cm}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the equation $(x+5)(x+8) = 42$
to solve for $x$. Then substitute $x$ into $(x + 3)(x + 6)$.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  The area of the frame is the area of the outer rectangle minus the area of the picture itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$,$W$,$FH$,$FW$ be the height, width, frame height and frame width.

We're given the following equations:

$H = W+3$

$W + 2 = FW$

$H + 2 = FH$

$FW \cdot FH - W\cdot H = 42$

It follows:

$(W+2)\cdot (H+2) - W\cdot H = 42$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $((H-3)+2)\cdot (H+2) - ((H-3)\cdot H)= 42$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $H^2+2H-H-2-H^2+3H  =42$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $4H = 44$

$\Leftrightarrow$  $H=11$

Alternatively, we can solve

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 0& 0 \end{array} \right)^{-1} \left( \begin{array}{c}
3  \\
-2  \\
-2 \\
46 \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{c}
H  \\
W  \\
FH \\
FW \end{array} \right)$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  The area of the frame is the area of the outer rectangle minus the area of the picture.

Comment: You're right, I fixed it.